# bash script to switch to random vpn profile every hour

Tags: bash, vpn, dns, openvpn, shell-script

i have a namecheap paid vpn service with hundreds of profiles (ovpn conf files), each allowing me to have an IP address from a different country.

i would like do switch between those profiles every hour, picking up a new IP and switching the `resolv.conf` to use the VPN DNS instead of mine (to avoid dns leak).

also, im only interested in USA IP addresses, so a filter would be nice.

lastly, i dont want a background service; the openvpn client should stay on the foreground printing all informational messages on screen, and a `ctrl + c` should terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

## vpn-gw-oneshot.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Each time this script is executed a random vpn config file is selected
# Better used with cron.hourly to switch IPs every hour
# Since i only use the vpn for netflix, there is a US filename filter
#
# A cada execucao deste script uma nova configuracao de vpn e escolhida
# Bom para ser usado em cron.hourly para trocar a cada hora
# Como meu uso de vpn e para netflix, estou filtrando para usar somente EUA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

exec 2>&1

[ $UID -eq 0 ] || { echo "Not root. Exiting script." ; exit 1 ; }

SCRIPTPATH=$(readlink -f $0)
SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname $SCRIPTPATH)
SCRIPTNAME=$(basename $SCRIPTPATH .sh)

PIDFILE=/var/run/$SCRIPTNAME.pid
PWDFILE=$SCRIPTDIR/namecheap.login

openvpn=$(which openvpn) || apt install -y openvpn
rename=$(which rename)   || apt install -y rename

cd $SCRIPTDIR

$rename -f -v 'y/ /-/' $SCRIPTDIR/tcp/*

POOL="$SCRIPTDIR/tcp/*-US-*.ovpn"
RNDMCFG=$(shuf -e ${POOL[@]} -n1)

echo "New random VPN conf selected: $RNDMCFG"

nmcli connection delete tun0

$openvpn --config $RNDMCFG --auth-user-pass $PWDFILE --writepid $PIDFILE --script-security 2 --up update-resolv-conf.sh --down update-resolv-conf.sh
```

## update-resolv-conf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# EN: Update resolv.conf to use the DNS defined by the VPN
# PT: Atualiza os DNS do resolv.conf para usar os definidos pela VPN
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get DNS defined by the VPN service
# Exit with error if the DNS array is empty
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getVpnDns() {
    for frgn_optn in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
        for fo in "${!frgn_optn}" ; do
            DNSARRAY+=( $(echo $fo | awk '/dhcp-option DNS/{print $3}') )
        done
    done
    [ -z "$DNSARRAY" ] && exit 1
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Write DNS to resolv.conf
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function writeResolvConf() {
    getVpnDns
    for DNS in ${DNSARRAY[@]} ; do
        echo "nameserver $DNS"
    done | tee /etc/resolv.conf
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Switch between resolv.conf configs on 'up' and 'down' events
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

case "$script_type" in
    up)
        mv -v /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.rag && writeResolvConf
    ;;
    down)
        mv -fv /etc/resolv.conf.rag /etc/resolv.conf
    ;;
esac
```